# Agregar valor a variable de una clase, desde otra clase:

Tags: php, poo, php7

Tengo esta clase:

```
class CustomerFormatterCore { 

private $status;

public function setStatus($status){
        $this->status=$status;
    }
    
public function getStatus(){
        return $this->status;
    }
    echo $this->getStatus();
}
```

A la variable `$status` o más bien a los métodos anteriores necesito agregarle un valor desde otra clase, que es la siguiente:

```
class CustomerFormCore{
public function __construct(CustomerFormatter $formatter) {
    parent::__construct($formatter);
}

 public function setActivate(){
    $this->formatter->setStatus('valorVariable'); //VALOR QUE DESEO
   echo $this->formatter->getStatus(); //Imprime el valor del metodo GET de la otra clase

}
```

Menciono que en la primer clase no imprime nada, pero en la segunda si me imprime el valor `valorVariable`

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Esto es php pero con todo siempre agrega en la etiquetas el lenguaje de programación. El framework y todo lo que creas que puede ayudar a que tu pregunta sea contestada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código debería quedar de esta forma:

```
<?php

class CustomerFormatterCore 
{ 

    private $status;

    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status=$status;
    }
    
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
    //echo $this->getStatus();
}


class CustomerFormCore
{
    public $algo;

    public function __construct(CustomerFormatterCore $formatter)
    {
        $this->algo = $formatter;
    }

    public function setActivate()
    {
        $this->algo->setStatus('valorVariable'); //VALOR QUE DESEO
        return $this->algo->getStatus(); //Imprime el valor del metodo GET de la otra clase
    }
}

$valor = new CustomerFormCore(new CustomerFormatterCore);
echo $valor->setActivate();
```

**Observaciones**

1. Esta línea de código no es necesaria:

   ```
    parent::__construct($formatter);
   ```

Pues te generaría un error de este tipo:

> Deprecated:  Cannot use "parent" when current class scope has no parent in

2. De hecho en la clase `CustomerFormCore` solo deberías declarar una propiedad, la cual será inicializada con el objeto que inyectas en el constructor de esta misma clase
3. Con lo anterior en mente, ese objeto te permitirá acceder a los métodos de la clase `CustomerFormatterCore` de esta forma:

   ```
    $this->propiedad->nombreMetodo();
   ```
4. Cuando hacemos la instancia de la clase `CustomerFormCore` le pasamos como argumento un `new CustomerFormatterCore`
5. Esta línea `echo $this->getStatus();` (en el renglón 12) así como esta también esta incorrecta remuevela

**Referencia**

- [Método constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.constructor)

**Edición**

- Considera escribir un código tipado con [declaraciones de tipo de devolución en los métodos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations) así como [la declaración de propiedades tipadas dentro de tus clases](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2)
- Aquí puedes leer [sobre los tipos válidos para devolución](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types)

---

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

class CustomerFormatterCore 
{ 

    private string $status;

    public function setStatus($status): void
    {
        $this->status=$status;
    }
    
    public function getStatus(): string
    {
        return $this->status;
    }
    //echo $this->getStatus();
}


class CustomerFormCore
{
    public object $algo;

    public function __construct(CustomerFormatterCore $formatter)
    {
        $this->algo = $formatter;
    }

    public function setActivate(): string
    {
        $this->algo->setStatus('valorVariable'); //VALOR QUE DESEO
        return $this->algo->getStatus(); //Imprime el valor del metodo GET de la otra clase
    }
}

$valor = new CustomerFormCore(new CustomerFormatterCore);
echo $valor->setActivate();
```

Comment: Antes de todo, Gracias por ayudarme! ....despues de que ya tenga esto lo que deseo es que valor agregado desde la segunda clase CustomerFormCore
se obtenga y muestre en la primer clase CustomerFormatterCore

Comment: Umm no lo considero viable pues el argumento dado a la función `setStatus` se obtiene en la clase `CustomerFormCore` y no en donde dicho método es declarado, en todo caso puedes intentar darle ese valor mas o menos así: `public function setStatus($status = 'valorVariable'): void` y de este modo ya no sería necesario que cuando invocas a dicho método en `CustomerFormCore` le pases un argumento pues usará el que tiene definido previamente

Answer (score 0):

Antes de todo, Gracias por ayudarme! ....despues de que ya tenga esto lo que deseo es que valor agregado desde la segunda clase     **CustomerFormCore**
se obtenga y muestre en la primer clase   **CustomerFormatterCore**